# Php Active Record Domain Expired (Their Site is currently down)

Tags: php

Php Active Record Domain Expired

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/

the above link is currently down.

is there any alternate link, so that i can refer docs.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that, this below link has enough information, about Php Active Record.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar